# Api data returns to 0 after information is called (React)

Tags: reactjs, api

I am fetching information about stocks in componentDidUpdate in React. The information that I want to fetch renders but after a few seconds the information reverts back to 0. I don't know why it is happening and I have tried to fetch it in componentDidMount first but the same thing keeps happening. I don't know how to go about solving this problem. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: '',
      stockSymbol: [],
      marketData: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      symbol1: [],
    };
  }

  typeSymbol = e => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase(),
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { userInput } = this.state;

    const urls = [
      `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols`,
      `https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops`,
    ];

    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(responses => {
        return Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()));
      })
      .then(responses => {
        this.setState({
          stockSymbol: responses[0],
          marketData: responses[1],
        });
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapShot) {
    const { userInput, symbol1 } = this.state;

    if (prevState.userInput !== userInput) {
      fetch(
        `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=${userInput}&token=brjo6knrh5r9g3ot7150`,
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(responses => this.setState({ symbol1: responses }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { stockSymbol, userInput, marketData, symbol1 } = this.state;

    const filteredSymbols = stockSymbol.filter(sym => sym.symbol === userInput);
    const foundMarket = marketData.find(market => market.symbol === userInput);

    const objData = () => {
      for (const stockData in symbol1) {
        console.log(`${stockData}: ${symbol1[stockData]}`);
      }
    };

    objData();

    const clock = new Date().toLocaleString();

    return (
      <div className="enterstock">
        <div className="fields">
          <span className="clock">{clock}</span>
          <h1 className="title">Enter Stock Symbol</h1>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="symfields"
            name="symbolname"
            onChange={this.typeSymbol}
          />
        </div>
        {filteredSymbols.map((stock, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="stockings">
              <div className="named">
                <h2 className="symbol">{this.state.userInput}</h2>
                <h2 className=" name" key={i}>
                  {stock.name}
                </h2>
              </div>

              {
                <h2 className="stocked price" key={i}>
                  Price: {symbol1.c}
                </h2>
              }
            </div>
          );
        })}
        ,
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have values in api ? I am seeing `0` values when I enter `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote`.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw, Hi, Yeah I'm sure. The data loads on the screen and after a few seconds it returns back to 0

Comment: what data? can you share your render method and point what becomes 0?

Comment: @diedu, Hi, it will be up in a minute.

Comment: @diedu, I thought it was my render method for a minute but I looped through the object and after a few seconds it returned to 0

Comment: I still don't understand what goes back to 0, `filteredSymbols`?

Comment: @diedu Symbol1 goes back to 0. I'm fetching it in the componentDidUpdate and once it loads the data goes back to zero

Comment: according to the logs you added the api respond with 0 values so I don't see anything wrong

Comment: @diedu What do you mean? How did I add the api with a repsonse of 0?

Comment: You appear to only update a single piece of state (*maybe you meant to process into array? IDK it isn't clear what you want*), but you are fetching multiple URLs, so I suspect one is returning quickly, with data, and the other later, with no data (or 0 or whatever it is you it is). The stock data for "TWTR" clearly is 0 according to your console log image.

Comment: @DrewReese I figured out what the problem is. When the symbol is typed in the info loads but the data from the characters is still fetching and when that loads it return zero because that symbol doesn't exist.